# package was not in the src folder

Tags: java, package, src, myeclipse

When I try to create a new package in the src folder of my web project,but it always  go to the  Libraries directory,  how to solve this problem?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That is not in the Libraries folder. it is shown under the Java Resources node in what I assume is the Project Explorer view, though the decorations look a bit strange; maybe you are using an old release of MyEclipse. Notice that the location can be determined by the indentation level; don't be fooled by the triangle that shows a node that can be expanded. The Java Resources node is not an actual folder. Check in the Navigator view or the Package Explorer view, or simply check in Windows Explorer (or equivalent file browser, if you use another operating system) to see where the folder actually is.

If you're still having problems, you need to provide the actual release of MyEclipse, that you're using, and give details of how you're trying to create the package.

Comment: Thank you,I found it is well in the package explore,so I close the package explore and then open it again,the problem disappears.Now I haven't met the problem yet